# Installing nokogiri on Pi Zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, raspberry-pi-zero

I am pretty new to this so please excuse me if it is a trivial question/isssue.

I have a Pi Zero (ARMv6) and have successfully installed Ruby (3.0.0p0) and Rails (7.0.4.3). Everything seems ok I was able to create a rails project etc.

However when running Rails server to start the server I get the below error

`/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.14.3-arm-linux/lib/nokogiri/3.0/nokogiri.so: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0xb38f3260 ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]`

I understand there is some issue with the platform but googling this has not provided much help on resolution.

I would appreciate any direction on this if possible.

I have tried several versions and installations on the Pi with no success as yet. I have followed the instructions on the nokogiri wiki also.